# Why is it not possible for me to access default value of @RequestParam without using quotes?

Tags: spring

I am using the Spring framework for this particular project, but I am wondering why I get an error 500 when I try to access http://localhost:8080/greeting when `parser.parseExpression(name)` param is not surrounded by quotes. When the code is `parser.parseExpression("'"+name+"'");` everything works. Why is that the case?

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
@ResponseBody
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    //value = "name", 
    
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("'"+name+"'");
    String message = (String) exp.getValue();
    System.out.println(message);
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, message));
}
```

Comment: Because your default value _isn't_ an expression. Is a non-default value going to be?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How should my default value be an expression?

Comment: As per what you're building by concatenating quotes, `"'World'"` would be an expression (for the string `"World"`). But why don't you just _use `name`_, what are you expecting the non-default values to be?

Comment: Simply because `World` isn't a valid expression whereas `'World'` is a valid expression. So leaving out the qoutes leads obviously to an illegal expression.

Comment: I think that might have answered my question. I will test it later

Comment: Yep, that work. Making  World an expression was what I was missing. Add your comment as an answer so I can accept it